# Formatting a dot separated word to bracketed word in Unix

Tags: string, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have the below line:

```
val CLMLINEFilterdDF = CLMLINE.filter(CLMLINEDF.CLM_LINE_ENCNTR_CD.isin("N","NA")  
&& CLMLINEDF.CLM_LINE_STTS_CD.isin("PD","APRVD","PDZB","APRZB","VOID")  
&& CLMLINEDF.HLTH_SRVC_TYPE_CD.notEqual( "ADA"))
```

I need it to be formatted as follows:

```
val CLMLINEFilterdDF = CLMLINE.filter(CLMLINEDF("CLM_LINE_ENCNTR_CD").isin("N","NA")  
&&  CLMLINEDF("CLM_LINE_STTS_CD").isin("PD","APRVD","PDZB", "APRZB","VOID")  
&&  CLMLINEDF("HLTH_SRVC_TYPE_CD").notEqual( "ADA"))
```

How can I achieve it in a Unix script/command?

I have tried this by using sed:

```
string="val CLMLINEFilterdDF = 
CLMLINE.filter(CLMLINEDF.CLM_LINE_ENCNTR_CD.isin("N","NA")  
&& CLMLINEDF.CLM_LINE_STTS_CD.isin("PD","APRVD","PDZB","APRZB","VOID")  
&& CLMLINEDF.HLTH_SRVC_TYPE_CD.notEqual( "ADA"))"

echo $string | sed -r "s/CLMLINEDF\.(.*)CLMLINEDF\.(.*)CLMLINEDF\(.*)/CLMLINEDF("\1")("\2")("\2")/g"
```

But it is not giving the correct results

Comment: please add your efforts done to solve this.. the downvotes are probably because you didn't show what you've tried.. also, it'd help to simplify sample and explain how the transformation should be applied..

Comment: Thanks, Added details

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -E 's/(CLMLINEDF)\.([^.]+)/\1("\2")/g' ip.txt
val CLMLINEFilterdDF = CLMLINE.filter(CLMLINEDF("CLM_LINE_ENCNTR_CD").isin("N","NA")  
&& CLMLINEDF("CLM_LINE_STTS_CD").isin("PD","APRVD","PDZB","APRZB","VOID")  
&& CLMLINEDF("HLTH_SRVC_TYPE_CD").notEqual( "ADA"))
```

- use single quotes unless you need double quotes. See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)
- `(CLMLINEDF)\.([^.]+)` match `CLMLINEDF` followed by `.` (meta characters need to be escaped to match them literally) followed by non `.` characters

  - See also manual for [Character Classes and Bracket Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions)
- `\1("\2")` re-arrange as needed
- `g` to replace all such matches